# How to call and declare a method with a variable amount of arguments?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods

I'm hopelessly trying to call a function with (int = amountCoefficients) amount of arguments, and declaring a function with that amount of arguments too.

What makes it harder is that for example amountCoefficients = 5, then it means that there's an array of 5 blocks that each have a value (double). So the first argument would have to be equal to the value of the first block of that array, the second argument would have to be equal to the value of the second block of that array etc.

And beforehand we don't know how many arguments we need, as that depends on the amount of doubles that are filled in by the user, so amountCoefficients could be equal to 2, 4, or any other positive integer.

I'm pretty new to Java and I really don't have no idea what to do. As you can see below I tried to do something with a for loop, but I don't think that works.

```
public class Interpol {

  public static void main(String []args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //acquire user input (polynomial coefficients and interval values x1 and x2)
        ArrayList<Double> polynomialCoefficients = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int amountCoefficients = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            polynomialCoefficients.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            amountCoefficients++;
        }
        String in = scanner.next();
        double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        double x2 = scanner.nextDouble();

        //call method f to determine the polynomial function
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < amountCoefficients; i++) {
        f
        }

        //call method findaroot to determine the root


        //print result

  }

}

public static double f(double x) {
//function of which a root is to be found
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method that takes a list or array. Then the method can use List.size() and array.length to process every object.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Double> polynomialCoefficients = new ArrayList<Double>();

    // get data
    ...

    process(polynomialCoefficients);
}

public void process(List<Double> coefficients){
    for(int i = 0; i < coefficients.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("Element " + i + ": " + coefficients.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [VarArgs notation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) to receive an arbitrary amount of parameters, although they will be converted into an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). This is achieved by a code like the following:

```
public void printOneEachLine(String... parameters) {
   for (String parameter : parameters) {
      System.out.println(parameter);
   }
}
```

And you can call it with:

```
printOneEachLine("msg1", "msg2");
printOneEachLine("msg3", "msg4", "msg5", "msg6");
```